# How to mock private method when I am testing public method in JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

How to mock private method when I am testing public method in JUnit 5.

```
class School{
    @Autowired
    private SchoolRepo schoolRepo;

    private String getSchoolName(String name){
         return "New Name :"+schoolRepo.findByName(name);
    }
    
    public String getFullNameWithSchool(){
        String schoolName = getSchoolName("HMS");
        String fullName = "SK "+schoolName;
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

I want to test (with JUnit5) `getFullNameWithSchool` method and mock the private method `getSchoolName` method.

Comment: Don't try to mock `getSchoolName`. Mock `SchoolRepo` instead.

Comment: Don't struggle with testing or mocking private methods. Test your public methods so that they *cover* all paths/branches/cases you want to test with the private ones. Moreover, since private members are implementation details they also candidates to be changed or deleted, burdening you a redundant test maintenance task.

Comment: And don't use field injection, but use constructor injection, that makes it a lot easier for testing.

Answer (score 1):

To give a code sample with the points given in the comments, what you want is something like

```
class School {
 private final SchoolRepo repo;

 // constructor injection
 @Autowired
 public School(SchoolRepo r) {
  repo = r;
 }

 private String getSchoolName(String name){
   return "New Name :"+schoolRepo.findByName(name);
 }
    
 public String getFullNameWithSchool(){
   String schoolName = getSchoolName("HMS");
   String fullName = "SK "+schoolName;
   return fullName;
 }
```

and in your test

```
class SchoolTest {
 private SchoolRepo repo = mock(SchoolRepo.class);

 // possible to use mock because of constructor injection
 private School school = new School(repo);

 @Test
 public void testSchoolName() {
  when(repo.findByName(any())).thenReturn("school");

  String name = school.getFullNameWithSchool();

  // assert the result is correct
  assertEquals(name, "SK New Name: school");
  // assert the query was performed with the fixed HMS string
  verify(repo).findByName("HMS");
 }
}
```

Note that I find it a bit weird that the query is done with a fixed String. "`School`" sounds like a domain class, I'd expect it to have several with a name each. I would also not expect it to autowire a repository, maybe you want to create a `SchoolService` that wired the repo and provides the name for a given `School` querying the repo.

Comment: Small tip, you don't need `@Autowired` on the constructor, spring will automatically use it if there is just a single constructor in that class.

Comment: @M.Deinum Good point. 
In our environment, we actually declare the fields as `final` and then use Lombok `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotations to generate the constructor. But I guess in this example it's fine to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: I have opinions on the use of lombok :).

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

You can't mock private methods with JUnit.

You can mock them with PowerMock.

A workaround would be to use reflection, but this is not recommended.

**Solution:**

Private methods should be called in public methods. Then you can test the public methods including the private method.

Example given: If you have a Service, test its public methods. If its public methods are calling private ones, they are tested automatically too.